# ¿Que Pasa Con Los Valores de Mitades de Pantalla?

Tags: vb.net

Por que pasa que los tiempos en dibujar una hipotenusa en pantalla no son los mismos desde la esquina superior izquierda al centro de pantalla, que para el centro de pantalla hacia la parte inferior derecha de pantalla? Es decir, los tiempos con el siguiente código varían

Ejemplo:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim B As New Bitmap(2000, 2000)
Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
Dim P As Pen = Pens.Black
Dim Respuesta As String = vbNullString
Dim Tiempos As Integer = 0
Dim CuentaVeces As Integer = 0
G.Clear(Color.White)

' Medimos el Tiempo de Dibujar una Hipotenusa en pantalla 1 ( 7 D )
Dim TiempoLinea1 As Date = Now
For CuentaVeces = 0 To 1000
    G.DrawLine(P, 0, 0, 1000, 1000)
Next
Tiempos = Now.Millisecond - TiempoLinea1.Millisecond
Respuesta = Respuesta & "Tiempo 1: " & Tiempos & vbCrLf

' Medimos el Tiempo de Dibujar una Hipotenusa en pantalla 2 ( 7 D )
Dim TiempoLinea2 As Date = Now
For CuentaVeces = 0 To 1000
    G.DrawLine(P, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000)
Next
Tiempos = Now.Millisecond - TiempoLinea2.Millisecond
Respuesta = Respuesta & "Tiempo 2: " & Tiempos & vbCrLf

MsgBox(Respuesta)
```

Comment: Esto es Cosa de la Largada de unas y otras variables en las que redundan los ciclos con números más largos en el segundo caso que en el primero. Por eso tarda más...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay un par de problemas con el código que nos muestras. Por un lado, estas usando `Now` para cronometrar el tiempo. Para hacer eso, .Net tiene una clase específica, que es [`Stopwatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) que es mas exacta.

Por otro, cuando vas a medir procesos que tardan tan poco tiempo, la forma de hacerlo es hacer varias iteraciones para que los resultados sean mas significativos.

He modificado un poco tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
Private Function Dibujar() As List(Of Int32)
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim B As New Bitmap(2000, 2000)
    Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(B)
    Dim P As Pen = Pens.Black
    Dim Respuesta As String = vbNullString
    Dim Tiempos As Integer = 0
    Dim CuentaVeces As Integer = 0
    G.Clear(Color.White)

    Dim listatiempos As List(Of Int32) = New List(Of Int32)

    ' Medimos el Tiempo de Dibujar una Hipotenusa en pantalla 1 ( 7 D )
    Dim sw As Stopwatch = New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()

    For CuentaVeces = 0 To 1000
        G.DrawLine(P, 0, 0, 1000, 1000)
    Next
    sw.Stop()
    listatiempos.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    ' Medimos el Tiempo de Dibujar una Hipotenusa en pantalla 2 ( 7 D )
    sw.Reset()
    sw.Start()
    For CuentaVeces = 0 To 1000
        G.DrawLine(P, 1000, 1000, 2000, 2000)
    Next
    listatiempos.Add(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    sw.Stop()
    Return listatiempos
End Function
```

De esta manera, la función usa `Stopwatch` y devuelve ambas mediciones para poder ir sumándolas desde el proceso que lo llama, que es el siguiente:

```
For j = 0 To 9
        Dim tiempo1, tiempo2 As Int32
        tiempo1 = 0
        tiempo2 = 0
        For i = 0 To 100
            Dim listatiempos As List(Of Int32)
            listatiempos = Dibujar()
            tiempo1 += listatiempos.ElementAt(0)
            tiempo2 += listatiempos.ElementAt(1)
        Next
        Debug.Print($"Iteración:{j + 1}{vbCrLf}Tiempo1:{tiempo1}{vbCrLf}Tiempo2:{tiempo2}{vbCrLf}")
    Next
```

Se llama a `Dibujar` 100 veces y se suman todos los tiempos `t1` y `t2`. Esto se hace 10 veces para sacar una estadística más consistente.

Resultados:

```
Iteración:1
 Tiempo1:2002
 Tiempo2:1991

Iteración:2
 Tiempo1:2029
 Tiempo2:2028

Iteración:3
 Tiempo1:2018
 Tiempo2:2029

Iteración:4
 Tiempo1:2028
 Tiempo2:2043

Iteración:5
 Tiempo1:2043
 Tiempo2:2048

Iteración:6
 Tiempo1:2049
 Tiempo2:2023

Iteración:7
 Tiempo1:1998
 Tiempo2:1984

Iteración:8
 Tiempo1:2000
 Tiempo2:2012

Iteración:9
 Tiempo1:1989
 Tiempo2:2005

Iteración:10
 Tiempo1:2001
 Tiempo2:1982
```

Como ves, los resultados son muy similares, y a veces `tiempo1` tarda más. y otras veces es `tiempo2` el mas lento.

Resumiendo, vemos que el tiempo que tarda en ejecutar un código depende de muchos factores y nunca es consistente al 100%. Por eso estas medidas de rendimiento no suelen servir para demasiado y yo desaconsejo totalmente preocuparse de estas cuestiones en procesos que tardan milisegundos. Al final se pierde el tiempo en microoptimizaciones que no suelen servir para mucho.

Comment: Suele Tardar Mas en la segunda que en la primera en muchos de los casos y aunque se hicieran en los mismos momentos seguiría pasando...
Estoy Intentando Igualar la Función Sabre mas en un Tiempo, ya que casí la tengo desarrollada la función drawline pero a diferencia de esa, espero que esta tarde lo mismo sea donde sea la línea tardara mas según sus tamaños de bucles ya que van 4 bucles con unos cuantos if's anidados fuera y dentro de ellos... A ver si lo resuelvo....